# Cannot load font 7x13bold while using xosview

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, fonts, remote-desktop

I have a fresh install of Xubuntu 16.04 (XFCE desktop). I've installed xosview, and when I try to run it I get:

```
xosview: display :2.0 cannot load font 7x13bold
```

I'm using vnc to access this machine (realvnc).
I can run xosview from another 14.04 Xubuntu just fine.

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I've found out that the fonts issue was caused by realvnc configuration:

- xosview opens when connected to the screen
- xosview doesn't open inside a vnc session

The solution was to run **vncinitconfig** as root:

```
$ gksu 'vncinitconfig -config'
```

Note that sudo doesn't help here since vncinitconfig queries the fonts with xset -q and it works when X11 display is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

It was an old bug, [check here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=547499). However, this can easily be solved by installing `xfonts-base` package as suggested in the bug reports. `xfonts-base` package has `7x13bold` font.

Open a terminal and Install it with this command

```
sudo apt-get install xfonts-base
```

Hope that will solve the problem.

Comment: Seems like it is already installed: "xfonts-base is already the newest version (1:1.0.4+nmu1)". I still get the error on the 7x13bold font.

Comment: @miluz Have you installed that package on the host machine your connecting using realvnc?

Comment: I found out what was wrong and wrote it as an answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: nice to see you solved your problem